# A question of determining when the entropy is maximum.

Tags: probability-theory, ergodic-theory

Y ={ 1, 2,...,r}

We are given that X is the set of two sided sequences with entries from  Y and T is the two sided shift on X, and *m* is a T invariant probability measure on X.

If $p_i = m(\{x \epsilon X |  x_0 = i\})$, and h(*m*) is the entropy of the dynamical system described above then it is required to show that h(*m*) $\leq$ $\sum_{n=1}^{r} p_i log p_i$ 
and that equality holds exactly when *m* is the product measure on X derived from assigning the probability $p_i$ to i in the space Y.

So I thought about adopting the technique used in Peter Walters' book where he calculates the entropy for the Bernoulli shift, but then I got stuck at the expression for *H*.

I believe I am to find out when this is maximum, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the entropy of $m$ is equal to
$$
h_m=\sup_\xi\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac{H_m(\xi_n)}{n},
$$
where the supremum is taken over all measurable partitions $\xi$ and where $\xi_n=\bigvee_{k=0}^{n-1}T^{-k}\xi$. But since the partition $\xi=\eta$ by cylinder sets of length $1$ is a generator, we have
$$
h_m=\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac{H_m(\eta_n)}{n}\le H_m(\eta)=-\sum_{i=1}^r p_i\log p_i
$$
(taking $n=1$ and so $\eta_n=\eta$). Of course, equality holds when $m$ is the Bernoulli measure since you know that the last expression is precisely the entropy of this measure.

Comment: I can observe that if m is the product measure, then the equality holds. I am not very clear on how we can say the converse. Are you using any result in particular? Or is it something very obvious?

Comment: Yes, it follows easily from convexity. But this is not asked in your question, the mean of "exactly" is not "if and only if"...

Comment: Then it appears I misunderstood the question. But in any case, I am unable to see how it follows from convexity. Could you possibly tell me?

Comment: That's not your question, and I have already replied, in detail. Some acknowledgment seems to be in order.

Comment: Yes, yes. Thank you, very much. And I should have led with that.